# Fluent NHibernate table-per-hierarchy mapping fails to discriminate child collections

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using table-per-hierarchy to persist `Cat` and `Dog` objects the same table. They both inherit from `Animal`. Another object (`AnimalOwner`) has two collection properties - `Cats` and `Dogs`. When the `AnimalOwner` is loaded from the db, all animals are loaded into one of the subclass collections instead of being differentiated by discriminator.

Here are the class definitions:

```cs
public abstract class Animal
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual AnimalOwner AnimalOwner { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
}

public class AnimalOwner
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Dog> Dogs { get; set; } = new List<Dog>();
    public virtual ICollection<Cat> Cats { get; set; } = new List<Cat>();
}
```

And the mappings:

```cs
public class AnimalMap : ClassMap<Animal>
{
    public AnimalMap()
    {
        Table("Animal");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Type").Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.AnimalOwner);
    }
}

public class CatMap : SubclassMap<Cat>
{
    public CatMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("Cat");
    }
}

public class DogMap : SubclassMap<Dog>
{
    public DogMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("Dog");
    }
}

public class AnimalOwnerMap : ClassMap<AnimalOwner>
{
    public AnimalOwnerMap ()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        HasMany(x => x.Cats)
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
        HasMany(x => x.Dogs)
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}
```

NHibernate is not respecting the subclass types when hydrating the collections. Here is a test that demonstrates the problem:

```cs
[Test]
public void CanMapAnimalOwner()
{
    var owner = new AnimalOwner();
    owner.Cats.Add(new Cat()
    {
        AnimalOwner = owner
    });
    owner.Dogs.Add(new Dog()
    {
        AnimalOwner = owner
    });
    Session.Save(owner);
    Session.Flush();
    Session.Clear();

    var refreshedOwner = Session.Get<AnimalOwner>(owner.Id);

    Assert.AreEqual(owner.Cats.Count, refreshedOwner.Cats.Count); // Failed: Expected: 1, But Was: 2
    Assert.AreEqual(owner.Dogs.Count, refreshedOwner.Dogs.Count);
}
```

I can see in the generated sql that when the `AnimalOwner` is hydrated, the discriminator column is not used to differentiate `Animal` types:

```sql
SELECT cats0_.AnimalOwnerId as animalownerid3_14_1_,
       cats0_.Id            as id1_14_1_,
       cats0_.Id            as id1_14_0_,
       cats0_.AnimalOwnerId as animalownerid3_14_0_
FROM   Animal cats0_
WHERE  cats0_.AnimalOwnerId = 1 /* @p0 */
```

Is this a limitation of NHibernate or is my mapping setup incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

We are using `xml` mapping, and in these cases we have to repeat the `where` condition even on collection elements:

```
<bag name="Cats" lazy="true" inverse="true" batch-size="50" cascade="all-delete-orphan"
     where="(Type='Cat')" >...
```

So, as far as I can guess from docs like these http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-set-and-bag.html in fluent we have the same option:

```
    HasMany(x => x.Cats)
        .Inverse()
        .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
        .Where("(Type='Cat')")
        ;
```